# Trouble Using Curl To OAUTH Foursquare

Tags: php, curl

I am logging a user in like this,

```
<?php
    header("Location: https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=foofoofoo&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/sandbox/fsAccept.php");
exit(0);
?>
```

I am then redirecting back to this accept page to get the token

```
<?php
$cur = curl_init("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
    ?client_id=foofoo
    &client_secret=foofoo
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/fsAccept.php
    &code=CODE");

    $cur;

  $fsResponse = json_decode('{ access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }', true);

    header("Location: http://www.example.com/sandbox"); 
?>
```

Then I am redirecting to my home page and var_dump the `$fsResponse`

This is what appears in the `var_dump`,

```
<?php
    var_dump("$fsResponse");
    ?>

string(0) ""
```

I think I might be setting this up wrong when in `fsAccept.php`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string that you're trying to `json_decode()` is not valid JSON, so `json_decode()` will return a boolean FALSE to signify failure.

You then don't store that `$fsResponse` anywhere, so once the script exits, the value's lost. It should go into `$_SESSION` so it can be preserved for the next request.

All that boils down to: `$fsResponse` in your curl script is useless, because your JSON is bad. That useless variable is lost when the script exits. And the `$fsResponse` in your var_dump() script has absolutely NO relation to the one in the curl script, other than sharing the same name.

So yes, you're getting `string(0) {}` because `$fsResponse` is undefined, and `"$fsResponse"` wraps an empty string around that undefined variable.

Comment: thanks, So if I am trying to get the `{ access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }` from the `http response` can I declare that $code = $_POST["code"] assuming thats the part of the url being returned where the token is stored? 
then json_decode($code) ????

Also is this what you mean by storing the `$fsResponse` Something like this?
`$_SESSION['fsResponse'] = $fsToken;` ??

Comment: this is what im trying to accomplish. https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth